# Запись компонента внутри компонента (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

Есть блок:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="first_block">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="second_block">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я начинаю изучать vue.js и хочу перезаписать этот блок как компонент, внутри которого есть еще компоненты. То есть, блок с id=main - это компонент, внутри которого два компонента (id=first_block, id=second_block). В тоже время внутри каждого из этих двух блоков есть еще компоненты (span, h1, p). Как реализовать компонент внутри компонента?

Comment: Стоит начать с того чтоб прочитать документацию. На русском даже есть.

Comment: Я прочитал про основы компонентов и регистрацию компонентов, искал инфу в интернете по вопросу - подходящего ответа не нашел

Comment: @СашаЛямин используйте [slots](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Если я запишу в slot, например, блок с id="first_block", то этот блок будет считаться компонентом? Потому что в дальнейшем я бы хотел удалять ненужные компоненты.

Comment: @СашаЛямин, нет, этот блок не будет считаться компонентом если вы не создадите компонент вставив туда этот блок... Вам нужно почитать документацию... вы явно "плаваете" в основах компонентов.